# Running c-source code on terminal gives weird output

Tags: c, terminal

So, I have been given excess to remote server and I copied my file via ssh in /opt directory. When I compile my code it gives no error but when I run a.out using

```
./a.out
```

It outputs weird set of characters like this :-

```
�gjx�}|_�]�������D���"�%
```

There are two c source file in the directory and while when I use

```
$stty sane
$tput clear
```

one files run successfully, but the other doesn't.
I have also tried :

```
Ctrl+C
reset
```

It doesn't work, in case if you'd need to see the terminal I'll provide that. I really can't understand what should I do.

My code :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static uint32_t map_size = 0x08000000;
static uint32_t map_base = 0x18000000;
static uint32_t map_addr = 0x00000000;

static char *dev_mem = "/dev/mem";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd;
    uint32_t *buf;
    if ((fd = open(dev_mem, O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) {
        printf("can't open /dev/mem .\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    buf = mmap((uint32_t *) map_addr, map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, map_base);
    if (buf == (void *) -1) {
        printf("Can't be mapped. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        map_addr = (long unsigned) buf;

    fwrite(buf, 1, map_size, stdout);

    // Fletcher's 32 bit checksum algorithm
    uint32_t sum1 = 0xffff, sum2 = 0xffff;
    uint32_t tempLen;
    while (map_size) {
        tempLen = map_size >= 359 ? 359 : map_size;
        map_size -= tempLen;
        do {
            sum2 += sum1 += *buf++;
        } while (--tempLen);
        sum1 = (sum2 & 0xffff) + (sum1 >> 16);
        sum2 = (sum2 & 0xffff) + (sum2 >> 16);
    }

    sum1 = (sum1 & 0xffff) + (sum1 >> 16);
    sum2 = (sum2 & 0xffff) + (sum2 >> 16);

    uint32_t sum = sum2 << 16 | sum1;

    printf("%u", sum);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
After commenting out `fwrite(buf, 1, map_size, stdout);`
the terminal didn't print weird characters, but now as I assumed it should be printing value of sum which is `uint32_t sum = sum2 << 16 | sum1;` it doesn't do so, instead now I get this message when I run `time ./a.out`

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

 real      0m4.327s
 user      0m4.270s
 sys       0m0.010s
```

Comment: Put the code *in the question*, please.

Comment: Okay, sure. I have provided the link though :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added :)

Comment: What do you think `fwrite(buf, 1, map_size, stdout);` would write? The contents of the memory would hardly be a simple string.

Comment: Questions need to be self-contained. In case you already haven't, do have a look at [ask].

Comment: hint: "self-contained" includes posting what it *should* do, not just the wrong output.

Comment: Okay, seems like fwrite was causing issue, when I commented out the line and ran time ./a.out it wasn't showing those weird symbol but now is printing "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"   . The code should have output the value of sum .

Comment: Try compiling with debugging enabled: `gcc -g -o test test.c` and running with `gdb`. Then running a backtrace to see what is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: the posted code causes the `gcc` (when run with the options: -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 ) results in 4 warnings, which need to be corrected

Comment: regarding: `printf("can't open /dev/mem .\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `perror("can't open /dev/mem .");` as that will output to `stderr`, both your message AND the reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: when calling `fwrite()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code contains the 'magic' number 359.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: ` map_addr = (long unsigned) buf;`  the variable: `map_addr` is never used (and was initialize to 0)  so why set it after the call to `mmap()`

Answer (score 1):

`map_size` is in bytes but `uint32_t buf` means the `*buf++` advances by 4 bytes each time until you have a buffer overflow and the code segfaults.

Note: You have various types and casts wrong that make the code unportable.